# Yii2 ManyToMany relation - Get Client window's data

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, relation

I have a small (no, not that small) probleme in my current project. Today I came across with Yii and viaTable but something is not working with it. I think something is wrong with the table linking.

**My goal would be to get all the data from the client windows(Ablak)
that is connected to a user via felhasznalo2ablak table.**

I have 3 tables. Felhasznalo(Users in English), Ablak(Client Window in English) and Felhasznalo2Ablak which is the via table.

Here are the table structures: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Felhasznalo(Model):

```
public function getWindows() {
return $this->hasMany(Ablak::className(), ['id' => 'ablak_id'])-       >viaTable('felhasznalo2ablak',['felhasznalo_id','id']);
}
```

Ablak(Model):

```
public function getUsers() {
return $this->hasMany(Felhasznalo::className(), ['id' => 'felhasznalo_id'])->viaTable('felhasznalo2ablak', ['ablak_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And the query in the controller:

```
$u = Felhasznalo::findOne(Yii::$app->user->getId());
$allowedWindows = $u->getWindows();
foreach ($allowedWindows as $aw) {
print_r($aw);
}
```

I want to get the ralational data from Ablak table that blongs to a specific user. It works but not tha way it should. Any ideas guys?

Thank you for your answers!

Gábor

Comment: It's not quite clear what your exact problem is. You say that you code works, "but not the way it should". What exactly is different from the expected output/functionality? If you can summarize the problem in a sentence or two and put it in the first paragraph or question title, you'll probably get more answers.

Comment: Actually it returns with the User data but i need to get the "Ablak" (windows) as result.

Comment: You can edit the question and put a summary of the exact problem in the first paragraph, instead of "something is not working with it".

Comment: Updated the post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the link in your Felhasznalo::getWindows()

```
public function getWindows() {
    return $this
        ->hasMany(Ablak::className(), ['id' => 'ablak_id'])
        ->viaTable('felhasznalo2ablak', ['felhasznalo_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Query for all "Windows"

```
$u = Felhasznalo::findOne(Yii::$app->user->getId());
$allowedWindows = $u->getWindows()->all();

print_r($allowedWindows);
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `felhasznalo2ablak` WHERE (`0`, `1`) IN ((2, 2))

I got this error when is changed my links

Comment: can you please show the full code of all three models?

Answer (score 0):

I forget to answer my thread. So the problem was solved by adding forign keys to my database structure and after that i generated the model files with gii.